# Samples on kubernetes helm golang client

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to create a service on kubernetes which manages helm charts on the cluster. It installs charts from a private chart repository. Since I didn't find any documents on how to use helm client api, I was looking for some samples or guidelines for creating a service on top of helm client.

Comment: If [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/cmd/helm/helm.go) is the file you are talking about then maybe you could run it via command line with the `-h` option and explore the implementations from the source itself?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**FOR HELM3**

As other answers pointed, with Helm 2, you need to talk with tiller which complicates stuff.

It is way more clean with Helm 3 since tiller was removed and helm client directly communicates with Kubernetes API Server.

Here is an example code to install a helm chart programmatically with helm3:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action"
    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/chart/loader"
    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/kube"
    _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth"
)

func main() {
    chartPath := "/tmp/my-chart-0.1.0.tgz"
    chart, err := loader.Load(chartPath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    kubeconfigPath := "/tmp/my-kubeconfig"
    releaseName := "my-release"
    releaseNamespace := "default"
    actionConfig := new(action.Configuration)
    if err := actionConfig.Init(kube.GetConfig(kubeconfigPath, "", releaseNamespace), releaseNamespace, os.Getenv("HELM_DRIVER"), func(format string, v ...interface{}) {
        fmt.Sprintf(format, v)
    }); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    iCli := action.NewInstall(actionConfig)
    iCli.Namespace = releaseNamespace
    iCli.ReleaseName = releaseName
    rel, err := iCli.Run(chart, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Successfully installed release: ", rel.Name)
}
```

Comment: there is no `Init` method defined on the Configuration type according to the docs.

Comment: Also how would a create a configuration from cluster certificates instead of the kubeconfig on filesystem?

Comment: Is there any solution we can transfer the parameters like `--set` `--set-file` of `helm install`?

Comment: @Aisuko take a look at my response below. You may pass the params to the `Run` functions via `map[string]interface{}` and if these are your installation values.

Comment: @turkenh How to get the list of charts deployed? I want to store the chart details like Name, Revision, Chart, etc. I am using HELM3 for chart deployment.

Comment: @Luffy you should use [list action](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/266c74f390c6dcd08ffbbe942df99d5557632806/pkg/action/list.go#L143). [Here](https://github.com/crossplane-contrib/provider-helm/blob/d335be22603378fbd2bcf97fdee149fcb0b9eb65/pkg/clients/helm/client.go) you can find how an action could be used in go, even we didn't need list action yet.

Comment: @LemurPwned Your example below helps to pass --set values but we need to pass a yml file (-f values.yaml) also how we can do that , is there a way to pass files also similar to installation values

Answer (score 5):

Since it took me some time to get this working here is a minimal example (no error handling, left details about kube config, ...) for listing release names:

```golang
package main

import (
  "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
  "k8s.io/helm/pkg/helm"
  "k8s.io/helm/pkg/helm/portforwarder"
)

func main() {
  // omit getting kubeConfig, see: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples

  // get kubernetes client
  client, _ := kubernetes.NewForConfig(kubeConfig)

  // port forward tiller
  tillerTunnel, _ := portforwarder.New("kube-system", client, config)

  // new helm client
  helmClient := helm.NewClient(helm.Host(host))

  // list/print releases
  resp, _ := helmClient.ListReleases()
  for _, release := range resp.Releases {
    fmt.Println(release.GetName())
  }
}
```

Comment: one key thing missing in the answer is: `host := fmt.Sprintf("127.0.0.1:%d", tillerTunnel.Local)`. See [link](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3663#issuecomment-451501588)

Comment: Of course, if trying to access Tiller from within the cluster, there is no need to do port forwarding. Just use, by default, `host := "tiller-deploy.kube-system.svc:44134"`

Comment: Any hint on how to install a release?

Comment: @rabenhorst How to get the list of charts deployed? I want to store the chart details like Name, Revision, Chart, etc. I am using HELM3 for chart deployment.

Comment: @Luffy this whole thread is about helm2 which uses tiller as a cluster side component. Maybe you can take a look on how the official helm3 CLI is doing it: https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/pkg/action/list.go

Comment: When running inCluster, make sure that the pod or job that's running this code has pods/portforward create permissions

Answer (score 4):

I was long trying to set up Helm installation with `--set` values, and I found that the best place to look currently available functionality is [official helm documentation example](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#simple-example) and [official Go docs for the client](https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/).

This only pertains to **Helm 3**.

Here's an example I managed to get working by using the resources linked above.

I haven't found a more elegant way to define values rather than recursively asking for the `map[string]interface{}`, so if anyone knows a better way, please let me know.

Values should be roughly equivalent to:
`helm install myrelease /mypath --set redis.sentinel.masterName=BigMaster,redis.sentinel.pass="random" ... etc`

Notice the use of `settings.RESTClientGetter()`, rather than `kube.Get`, as in other answers. I found `kube.Get` to be causing nasty conflicts with k8s clients.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action"
    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/chart/loader"
    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/cli"
    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/release"
)

func main(){
    chartPath := "/mypath"
    namespace := "default"
    releaseName := "myrelease"

    settings := cli.New()

    actionConfig := new(action.Configuration)
    // You can pass an empty string instead of settings.Namespace() to list
    // all namespaces
    if err := actionConfig.Init(settings.RESTClientGetter(), namespace,
        os.Getenv("HELM_DRIVER"), log.Printf); err != nil {
        log.Printf("%+v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // define values
    vals := map[string]interface{}{
        "redis": map[string]interface{}{
            "sentinel": map[string]interface{}{
                "masterName": "BigMaster",
                "pass":       "random",
                "addr":       "localhost",
                "port":       "26379",
            },
        },
    }

    // load chart from the path 
    chart, err := loader.Load(chartPath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    client := action.NewInstall(actionConfig)
    client.Namespace = namespace
    client.ReleaseName = releaseName
    // client.DryRun = true - very handy!


    // install the chart here
    rel, err := client.Run(chart, vals)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Printf("Installed Chart from path: %s in namespace: %s\n", rel.Name, rel.Namespace)
    // this will confirm the values set during installation
    log.Println(rel.Config)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*I was looking for the same answer, since I do know the solution now, sharing it here.*

What you are looking for is to write a wrapper around helm library.

First you need a client which speaks to the tiller of your cluster. For that you need to create a tunnel to the tiller from your localhost. Use [this](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/cmd/helm/helm.go) (its the same link as kiran shared.)

1. Setup the Helm environement variables [look here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/cmd/helm/helm.go#L87)
2. Use [this](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/cmd/helm/helm.go#L271) next. It will return a helm client. (you might need to write a wrapper around it to work with your setup of clusters)

After you get the `*helm.Client` handle, you can use helm's client API given [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/pkg/kube/client.go). You just have to use the one you need with the appropriate values.

You might need some utility functions defined [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/pkg/chartutil/load.go), like loading a chart as a folder/archive/file.

If you want to do something more, you pretty much locate the method in the [doc](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/helm) and call it using the client.