# How to pass YAML files while installing charts using Helm Go SDK

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We are using the Go [helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action](https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action) package to install Helm charts.
We are able to pass installation values to Helm chart `Run` functions via `map[string]interface{}`, as in [Samples on kubernetes helm golang client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692719/samples-on-kubernetes-helm-golang-client):

```golang
rel, err := client.Run(myChart, vals)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    panic(err)
}
```

But we have a `values.yaml` file also which was passed as `-f values.yaml` when installing charts from the CLI.
Is there a way to pass these `values.yaml` files via the action Go package during installation (`client.Run()`)?

Or do we need to unmarshal the YAML file and pass that also as map:

```golang
data2 := make(map[string]interface{})
yfile2, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./utils/values.yaml")

fmt.Println(err)
err = yaml.Unmarshal(yfile2, &data2)
```

Comment: The approach looks fine. Unmarshal the values.yaml file to `map[string]interface{}` and pass it to `client.Run`. Do you have any errors doing so?

Comment: Also, it is recommended to use run with a cancellable context - https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action#Install.RunWithContext

Comment: @Inian Yes some expected pvs are not getting mounted if doing marshaling way, though i am looking into it. Purpose of the question was if there is some simple way to pass yaml files using action go package without marshaling.

Answer (score 2):

One straightforward thing to do could be to reuse the [helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/cli/values](https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3@v3.9.3/pkg/cli/values) package.  This has the logic to handle the `-f` option (and also `--set` and its variants) and return a unified `map[string]interface{}`.  This could look like:

```golang
import (
        "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/cli"
        "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/cli/values"
        "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/getter"
)

envSettings := cli.New()
providers := getter.All(envSettings)
options := values.Options{
        ValueFiles: []string{"./utils/values.yaml"},
}
theValues := options.MergeValues(providers)
```

Now `theValues` is the `map[string]interface{}` that results from reading those files.  You can customize the values further if required (as Go data) and then pass that to `install.Run()`.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know that. So it internally does a stat and does an unmarshal? I thought I had to raise a new feature request - https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/11225